# Asp.Net Asynchronous Page Stopping other requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, asynchronous

I have a aspx page to do asynchronous calls. The page gets data from the database(spends 30 seconds in the stored procedure) and then returns the results to the client. This is done through a jquery post.

The problem is that while it does the stored procedure for 30 seconds, the rest of my site can't make any requests.

I have `<%@ Page Async="true" AsyncTimeout="600" Language="C#"...` in the .aspx

My .aspx.cs contains:

```
      private SqlConnection _connection;
        private SqlCommand _command;
        private SqlDataReader _reader;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddOnPreRenderCompleteAsync(BeginAsyncOperation, EndAsyncOperation);
        }

        protected IAsyncResult BeginAsyncOperation(object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, object state)
        {
            IAsyncResult result = null;
            try
            {
                SqlConnectionStringBuilder ConnectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder("**MyConnectionStringGoesHere**");
                ConnectionStringBuilder.AsynchronousProcessing = true;
                _connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString);

                _command = new SqlCommand("GetSiteUpdates", _connection) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };
                _connection.Open();
                result = _command.BeginExecuteReader(cb, state);
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {}
            return result;
        }

protected void EndAsyncOperation(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            _reader = _command.EndExecuteReader(ar);
            try{
                   //Do Code Here
                   //Set Builder string here
                   Response.Clear();
                   Response.Write(builder.ToString());
                   _reader.Close();
                   Response.End();
            }
            catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException)
            {
                try { _reader.Close(); }
                catch { }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                try { _reader.Close(); }
                catch { }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this is session locking. When a page opens with Read and Write access to the session (which is by defualt), it will lock the session preventing any other pages that require the session from loading.

So two things here.

1. A quick fix is to drop the session access and / or set it to read only for this page.
2. Since you're only returning JSON, you should use an ASP.Net handler (ashx) as this produces less overhead than an aspx page and, by default, has no session access (this can be added if necessary).

Also, I'm not sure why you're using async here. Since IIS has to wait until the page returns a response and since this page is doing nothing else, I see no benefit to using it asynchronously.

Comment: I've decided to make it asynchronous since the database takes 30 seconds to return data, and in those 30 seconds I want my threads on the server to respond to other requests by other users, etc.

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx, requests for different session IDs can access the session concurrently.  Only another request for the same session ID would need to wait for the lock.

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I needed - went with the ashx option.

Comment: Byron, I think you are using async to try and resolve this problem when it's really session locking. It's only going to lock the current session (so, another user coming into your server should be unaffected). Using async, if that's all your page does, is actually a waste of resources and you don't gain anything. I'd drop it and stick to using the ashx since it sounds like the session locking was your main issue here.

Comment: Kris, Byron accesses remote resource (database) in his request handler. It is good idea to use asynchronous processing for it if performance of servier (number of requests it can handle simultaneously). Synchronous request blocks thread till it is completed, as result it limits number of reuests that can be handled at the same time due to restriction on number of threads. This is usually not an issue for small traffic sites.

Comment: Byron - you also may use EnableSessionState="ReadOnly" to solve some sceanrios (when only readers need to access state for particular session). - See http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/207800860;jsessionid=1T3HGGTUFD4YTQE1GHRSKHWATMY32JVN

Comment: Alexei, I haven't seen anything other than some articles just saying "it's faster". Do you know of any documentation regarding the performance increase? The web server _has_ to keep the connection open in order for it to even work so I'm a little confused as to how IIS can keep a connection open but free up a request thread while moving this processing to yet another thread. That seems like an artificial increase to requests to me but I'm curious as to how the numbers add up and to the internals.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing against a proper IIS instance? If you are using the development server built in to Visual Studio then you will experience this single threaded behaviour.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but after publishing to IIS, I still had this problem.

Comment: While the Visual Studio development server is different (everything, regardless of settings, is processed by the ASP.Net engine), this type of behavior should not be different than IIS. The development server allows for multi-threaded applications without issue.